# How send a post request in react native application for whmcs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, whmcs

i want to build a app with react native for whmcs and i use the whmcs api but i cant send the request parameters as data?!!!
when i set the parameters in url the request work fine but in data whmcs not read my parameters

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: baseUrl+`?action=GetClientsProducts&username=${UserName}&password=${Password}&accesskey=${accessKey}&responsetype=json&clientid=${this.state.user_token}`, 
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        self.setState({
            data:response.data.products.product,
            load:true
        })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        self.setState({refresh:true,})
    }); //this is work fine
        //
```

But in data not work???

```
let myData={username:'myusername',password:'mypassword',accesskey:'myaccesskey',responsetype:'json',...}
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: baseUrl, 
        data:myData
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` parameter send the provided object as the body of the request. You're trying to send query params, to do this you'll need to use the`axios.post` function like so:

```js
axios.post(baseUrl, null, {
    params : {
        username : 'username',
        password : 'password',
        accesskey : 'key',
        responseType : 'json'
    }
});
```

You could also do the same with the `axios` function but moving your query params from the `data` parameter to the `params` as shown above.

Comment: my problem is that i want to upload a file as attachment but the whmcs give base64 version of file and if i convert a image to base64 the url is too big and whmcs give me this error 414 Request-URI Too Long

Comment: Why do you need to send it as part of the URL?